# Compare strings in array to other strings array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

I'm looking for a good way to compare strings in one array to strings in another array. If one or more strings match the strings in the other array, do something with this element where the matched string is = element attr + other element attr.

Help much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

```
    var cSC = $('.cpa');

    var existingSel = cSC.map(function () {  
        return $(this).attr("data-fd") + $(this).attr("data-t");
    }).get();


    console.log(existingSel);


    if (sessionStorage.trueDates) {
        var oldArr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.trueDates);
    }
    else {
        var oldArr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.calDT);
    }

   var uiSel = $(".class");
   var calDataStore = uiSel.map(function(){
            return  $(this).attr("data-fd") +  $(this).attr("data-t");
        }).get();
            sessionStorage.setItem("calDT", JSON.stringify(calDataStore));
        console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.calDT));

        var newArr = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.calDT);

        var trueArr = newArr.concat(oldArr);

        sessionStorage.setItem("trueDates", JSON.stringify(trueArr));



    });
    if (sessionStorage.trueDates) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.trueDates));
    }
```

I want to compare these arrays (existingSel & oldArr)

```
    for(var ii=0; ii < existingSel.length; ii++){
        if(existingSel[ii] == oldArr[ii]){
            console.log('Match found!');
        }
    }
```

But they return nothing (no console message)

I have a reset button that does this on click:

```
  sessionStorage.removeItem("trueDates");
  sessionStorage.setItem("calDT", "0");
```

Comment: What have you  tried so far?

Comment: I added my code now, see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over first array and check if element is in second array using `indexOf`:

```
var array1 = ["foo", "bar" , "baz" , "quux"];
var array2 = ["asd", "bsd", "foo", "quux"];

for(var i=0; i < array1.length; i++) {
   if (array2.indexOf(array1[i]) != -1) {
      console.log('found ' + array1[i] + ' in second array');
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot! this is working perfectly, now the last thing i need is to remove a string from array2 if a class is removed from an element, is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: @Plainawesomeweb To remove element from array use `.splice(index, 1)` array method.

Answer (score 0):

You just iterate the array of each like and compare like so:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4];
var array2 = [1,3,5,6];

for(var ii=0; ii < array1.length; ii++){
      if(array1[ii] == array2[ii]){
      //do some stuff here
  }
}
```